# DER input, Integer tag error when connecting WSDL in Java

Tags: java, wsdl, keytool

I generated a certificate using keytool from a .pfx file and included in the system property as mentioned below.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\cert.crt");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.KeyPassword", "password");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "SSL");
```

As I have included the "debug" property, I get the below message in Console when I execute the required method.

```
keyStore is : C:\cert.crt
keyStore type is : pkcs12
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
default context init failed: java.io.IOException: DER input, Integer tag error
```

The exception details are provided below. What are the things that I am doing wrong here?

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl).
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:234)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:197)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:93)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:179)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:186)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.createSocket(HttpsClient.java:362)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:145)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:411)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:525)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:272)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:923)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:793)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:251)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:118)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1245)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:220)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:147)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:125)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:68)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:102)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:327)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:285)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:65)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:42)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:37)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:945)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: DER input, Integer tag error
    at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getInteger(DerInputStream.java:151)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1202)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1185)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl.getDefaultKeyManager(DefaultSSLContextImpl.java:150)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl.<init>(DefaultSSLContextImpl.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1221)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Why do you think that .cer file can be used as pkcs12 keystore?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have never used these in my career and trying out in my new projects. Still learning. Please guide me on what to be used.

Comment: This is where I referred to this approach - http://code.google.com/p/misc-utils/wiki/JavaHttpsUrl

Comment: You need to import your cert (cert.crt) into a Java Key Store (jks) with the keytool utility that comes with the jdk. This is a pretty good guide but you need to work out what format your cert is (PEM, DER…) - https://www.baeldung.com/java-import-cer-certificate-into-keystore. Also put how you generated the certificate  with keytool in the question

Answer (score -1):

This error usually occurs when the type of certificate the service expects is different from the one you created or are requesting with. One thing to make sure first is the type of cert you want either "PKCS12" or "JKS".

In my case instead of using the default instance, I specified "JKS" like below and it worked. If you use default instance, it is "PKCS12".

```
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
trustStore.load(null, null);
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

FileInputStream fis = null;
FileOutputStream fos = null;

fis = new FileInputStream(<your cert file>);
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(fis);
fis.close();

trustStore.setCertificateEntry(<cert name/alias>, certificate);
fos = new FileOutputStream(<path of the file to write to>);
// "changeit" is the default password that is used.
trustStore.store(fos, "changeit".toCharArray());
fos.close();
```